# Java - static class and its parent initialization

Tags: java, inheritance, static-methods

I'm pretty new in Java and I hope that somebody will help me to resolve this problem.

I have to create a method that will be called in the following way:
`Child.getI()`;

**Parent.java**

```
package MyTest;

public class Parent {

    private static int i;
    public Parent(int x){
        i = x;
    }

    public static int getI(){
        return i;
    }
}
```

**Child.java**

```
package MyTest;

public class Child extends Parent {

    public Child(int x) {
        super(x);
    }
}
```

How should i design my classes so when I call `Child.getI()`, it will first initialize the `Child` class? It definitely doesn't work in the way I did it.

Comment: You should really check the meaning of `static`. If you´d done so you´d notice that `How should i design my classes so when i call Child.getI(), it will first initialize the Child class` doesn´t really make sense, aswell as setting the `static` variable `i` in the `Parent` `Constructor` should not be correct.

Comment: `static` fields and methods aren't inherited. `i` and `getI()` belong to `Parent` alone. If this is something that you're trying to do then it would suggest that there are problems with your design. What are you actually trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: I think your first mistake is setting static variables from a constructor. This can be done and is sometimes useful, but if you do this as a beginner, it means you don't understand what a constructor is supposed to do. It is supposed to initialize the current instance of the class, not common resources like statics. These should be initialized with an initializer or a static block, and changed with a static method.

Comment: I am creating automated testing framework based on page object model. I wan't to create a base class for every UI component. For example i wan't to create a base class for UI components and to extend it with specific component classes. It's important to me that users of my framework will have the easiest way to use it. This is why i have static methods.

Comment: I´d start with a basic java tutorial beforing creating such a framework, as the current code screams that you didn´t go through the java basics.

Comment: RealSkeptic, i didn't find way to pass value of my field to initializer block.

Comment: Thanks for everybody who answered. I'm going to learn better Java basics.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Child.getI()` you don't call method on class instance (new object instance will not be created), however you call it on `Class<Child>`.

When java runtime will first time find `Child` the classloader will load `Child` class and its base classes and then will execute class static fields and blocks init. Nothing more from your code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Thanks to everybody. It looks like there is no really right answer to my question and i have to learn better Java basics (like static and inheritance concepts).
2. I'm going to use the workaround suggested by Therkon. This is still gives me possibility to change multiple classes behavior when i have to change parent class methods only and it still leaves the methods to be static so i can call it in the way i wanted - Child.getI();

Parent.java

package MyTest;

public class Parent {

```
private static int i;
public Parent(int x){
    i = x;
}

public static int getI(){
    return i;
}
```

}

Child.java

package MyTest;

```
public class Child extends Parent {

    public Child(int x) {
    super(x);
}

public static int getI() {
    final int i = 3;
    return ((Parent)new Child(i)).getI();
}

}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could design your code that way. This is one solution with static methods and one solution without static methods.

Parent.java

```
package MyTest;

public class Parent {

    private int i;
    private static int i2;
    public Parent(int x){
        i = x;
        i2 = x;
    }

    public int getI(){
        return i;
    }

    public static int getI2() {
        return i2;
    }
}
```

Child.java

```
   package MyTest;

    public class Child extends Parent {

        public Child(int x) {
            super(x);
        }

        public static int getI() {
          final int i = 3;
          final Parent parent = new Child(i);
          return parent.getI();
        }

        public static int getI2() {
          final int i = 3;
          final Parent parent = new Child(i);
          return parent.getI2();
        }

    }
```